# Flutter app keep sending me this on log when restart 'Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i keep getting this error in my app when i debug my app, the error say

```
W/DynamiteModule( 6570): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 6570): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 6570): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

whenever i restart my flutter app. it keep giving me this error, and when i tried to take data from firestore it didn't gave me any. after i go to other page and go back to the original page. the data load and the error gone.

i've been following some of other relate question and there's no helpful answer for that, this what i've been tried earlier

- adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` to the `AndroidManifest.xml` at android > App > main > AndroidManifest.xml
- tried to do `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` and still didn't solve the problem.
- adding this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to the AndroidManifest.xml and remove it again and still not solve the problem.
- i've been check the pubspec.yaml and do dependencies update and still yet there's no sign of the problem been solve.
- debug on emulator, and 2 real device still gave me the same problem.
- tried to delete the app on device and built it again, and nope
- `multiDexEnabled true` added to `app/build.gradle`
  [image]

yep and the issue still there. and the problem only show up when being first open/run. and after i goes to other, it'll comeback to normal.

Comment: Have you checked this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63992366/flutter-local-module-descriptor-class-for-providerinstaller-not-found) & this github [link1](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/4447) & [link2](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/2053)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya yeps, tried all of them and the error still there.