# firebase messaging [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception:

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hell everyone so im building an app and i want to implement firebase messaging, but i cant get it to work. Everything works up to great till this line of code

```
 void getToken() async {
    String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    print("this is the token" + token!);
  }
```

the app asks for permission to send messages but when it tries to get the token for the device it throws this error.

```
E/flutter ( 5116): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
E/flutter ( 5116): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
E/flutter ( 5116): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:296:18)
E/flutter ( 5116): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5116): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:499:43)
E/flutter ( 5116): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5116): #3      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.getToken (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:224:11)
E/flutter ( 5116): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5116): #4      _LobbyState.getToken (package:myfuji/screens/Lobby.dart:61:21)
E/flutter ( 5116): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5116): 
W/DynamiteModule( 5116): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 5116): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 5116): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
D/EGL_emulation( 5116): app_time_stats: avg=84.66ms min=17.81ms max=417.64ms count=11
```

Can anyone please point me to the right direction? Much appreciated. I have also included the complete code for that section

````
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myfuji/fetchInfo/userCart.dart';
import 'package:myfuji/screens/Chat.dart';
import 'package:myfuji/screens/News.dart';
import 'package:myfuji/screens/mindYoBis.dart';
import 'package:myfuji/screens/Shop.dart';
import '../fetchInfo/my_Drawer.dart';
import 'SignIn.dart';

class Lobby extends StatefulWidget {
  const Lobby({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Lobby> createState() => _LobbyState();
}

class _LobbyState extends State<Lobby> {
  String? mToken = " ";

  FirebaseMessaging messaging =
      FirebaseMessaging.instance; //getting firebase messaging ready for use

  List<String> docIDs = [];

  Future getDocId() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').get().then(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach(
            (document) {
              print(document.reference);
              docIDs.add(document.reference.id);
            },
          ),
        );
  }

  late final CollectionReference usersCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('user'); //gets 'user' collection from firebase

  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  int index = 0;

  final screen = [
    const News(),
    const mindYoBis(),
    const Shop(),
    const Chat()
  ]; // lower drawer

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestPermission();
    getToken();
  }

  // get device token and print
  void getToken() async {
    String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    print("this is the token" + token!);
  }
  // end

  // request permission to get message from app
  void requestPermission() async {
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print('User granted permission');
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
        AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      print('User granted provisional permission');
    } else {
      print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
    }
  }
// end of permission

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        endDrawer: my_Drawer(documentId: auth.currentUser!.uid),
        appBar: AppBar(
          // cart bottom/icon
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart,
              ),
              onPressed: () => {
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            const userCart())) //takes user to cart
              },
            ),
            Builder(builder: (context) {
              return IconButton(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.menu,
                ),
                onPressed: () => {Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer()},
              );
            }),
          ],

          title: const Text('Welcome'),
          leading: Image.asset('src/logo.png'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        ),

        //body
        body: screen[index], // screen navi
        //body
        bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBarTheme(
          data: NavigationBarThemeData(
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              indicatorColor: Colors.deepPurple[100],
              labelTextStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                  const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))),
          //lower bottom navigation
          child: NavigationBar(
            labelBehavior: NavigationDestinationLabelBehavior.onlyShowSelected,
            selectedIndex: index,
            onDestinationSelected: (index) =>
                setState(() => this.index = index),
            destinations: const [
              NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
              NavigationDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.emoji_food_beverage_rounded),
                  label: 'Local Bis'),
              NavigationDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag), label: 'Shop'),
              NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.chair), label: 'Games')
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //sign out
  signOut() async {
    await auth.signOut();
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SignIn()));
  }
}
```code
````

Comment: What platform are you testing the code on? Is it iOS, Web, or Android?

Comment: andriod studio (flutter)

Comment: please check the suggestions in this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64343699/failed-to-load-providerinstaller-module-no-acceptable-module-found-local-versi) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63992366/flutter-local-module-descriptor-class-for-providerinstaller-not-found)